# JList setListData threading issues

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlist

I'm loading contents of a file to `JList` component. If I do the loading in main thread, everything seems to be OK - contents are loaded. But when I move loading code to separate thread, select an item in a list and try to reload the list, I get random `NullPointer` or `IndexOutOfBounds` exceptions. I'm sure this is some kind of Swing threading issue, but can't determine what.

This is my thread code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    List<String> textLines = null;
    textLines = splitter.split(model.getLedMaxChars(), textLoader.loadText(file));
    listener.onTextLoaded(textLines);//listener is in main Swing code
}
```

Controller is responsible for listening:

```
@Override
public void onTextLoaded(List<String> textLines) {
    view.fileLoaded(model.getCurrentFile());
    view.setTextLines(textLines);
    view.enableListComponent();
}
```

And the view updates:

```
public void setTextLines(List<String> textLines) {
    jList.setListData(textLines.toArray());
}
```

I've tried to leave thread to hang by adding `while(true);` loop - then everything works OK. If I hit reload without selecting item in a list, everything works too.

Could anyone explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: you're missing that nearly every single operation related to Swing components has to be done on the EDT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing components are usually not thread-safe. This means that only the Swing worker thread should do any modifications:

```
Runnable worker = new Runnable() {  
  public void run() {
     jList.setListData(textLines.toArray());
  } 
};
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(worker);
```

See also:

- http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html
- http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html

Answer (score 2):

Swing is not thread safe, so when you are manipulating GUI elements from other threads many weird things may occur. In your case the simplest solution (but probably not the best) would be to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`